# what is the persistent c++ system?

Tags: c++

plz Send me the answer of the following question.

what is the persistent c++ system?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by `persistent C++ system` ?

Comment: plz send me cookies, then I may answer

Comment: Well, if people are going to paste in homework, they could at least paste in the entire question ;)  Or let us know what book they are using and give us the page number.

Comment: We do some people even answer questions stated like that ?!

Comment: @klez: Dude that's the best "plz send de codz" response I've seen yet. I may borrow at some point in the future, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier do as you wish :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A** persistent C++ system *could be* a software layer or an entire [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141/good-orm-for-c-solutions) responsible for the persistence of C++ objects in a database,

**The** persistent C++ system doesn't mean anything out of context.

Answer (score 0):

A persistent C++ system uses persistent C++ objects. 
Those are objects that continue to exist after the method exits.

For example see [persistent C++](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/f3-88429.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, but:

Persistence in C++ is generally usually handled by serialization.